# Unable to import database into my live phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, localhost, local

I tried to import SQL file into my live server using PHPMyAdmin GUI but I'm stuck!
Note!
I've exported the DB from my localhost and trying to import it into my live server.

The errors
Static analysis:

11 errors were found during analysis.

```
Unexpected character. (near "{" at position 321)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "DOCTYPE" at position 2)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "HTML" at position 10)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "html" at position 16)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "lang" at position 21)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "'en'" at position 26)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "dir" at position 31)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "'ltr'" at position 35)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "head" at position 42)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "meta" at position 48)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "charset" at position 53)
```

SQL query:

html{display: none

MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '
<meta na' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!
Just find 'create database...' and replace the db name with server db name.
ie, domain_db_name you can find it on c-panel